# Solve Global Optimization in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, optimization, mathematical-optimization, data-analysis

I have to find x that minimizes the following unconstrained optimization problem:

f(x) = sigma{k}(x'*A_k*x - b_k)^2;

where A_k are 4 x 4 positive definite matrices (A_1, A_2,...A_k), x is 4 x 1 vector and b_k are scalars (b_1,b_2,...b_k). I have solved this problem by using Nelder-Mead and Newtons Method in MATLAB but since this non-linear OP has multiple local minima(multiple x that solve this OP), I am not able to choose the best solution of x. Is there any way to solve this OP in MATLAB such that x will always be a global minimum(best/global solution)? I would highly appreciate suggestions.

Comment: Your problem as written isn't convex, making it more difficult to ascertain whether you are at a global minimum or simply a local minimum.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be non-convex and because of non-convexity it has multiple local minima. Two different algorithms have yielded two different solutions (x) so I am not sure which one to consider as the best solution of this OP. Any suggestion on how to deal with this kind of problem?

Comment: One approach is to enumerate all local minima and find the lowest.

Comment: I had thought of that; but since x is a vector I wasn't sure how to proceed with that. I thought there might be some global optimization algorithms to yield global minima for such non-linear OP's.

Comment: it goes from 1 to 180.

Comment: @Matthew based on your suggestion I am finding all the local minimal (by changing the initial guess vector in fminsearch of MATLAB) and choosing the solution x that yields the minimal value of the objective function. Any comments on this?

Answer (score 1):

[BARON](http://archimedes.cheme.cmu.edu/?q=baron) is a very good global solver and it can be called from Matlab.

I quickly tried your model with Baron (not from Matlab but from GAMS) using some random data and that seemed to solve quite fast:

[image]

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. I will try this out :)